# MSAL UserTokenCache not persisted on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've attempted to authenticate users using Azure B2C and MSAL, but have stumbled upon some user experience issues.

When I debug my app, I usually don't have to sign in as I'm already authenticated and the token is still valid. However, if I switch from Debug to Release and then test the app, the AquireTokenSilentAsync method doesn't seem able to retrieve a valid token from the UserTokenCache. My assumption is that the UserTokenCache is cleared every time the app is closed. Somehow this doesn't happen in Debug mode, I guess it's because the cache is persisted between deploys.

I'm getting the authentication result this way, but have tried different overloads without any success.

> AuthenticationResult ar = await
>   App.PCApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes, "",
>   App.Authority, App.SignUpSignInpolicy, false);

So, when I sign in, close and re-enter the app I still need to login again.

I'm fully aware MSAL is still in preview, but I haven't been able to find any issues (yet) related to this behaviour. Is this a known issue and is there a workaround available?

Looking at the MSAL source code, I can clearly see that the UserTokenCache is using Android SharePreferences for persistance, and this works perfectly in debug mode. So, either this is a bug/missing implementation, or I'm failing to see something obvious..

Comment: I've done a blog post about what I did to figure out this issue over here: http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2016/12/05/msal-token-not-stored-on-android - the slightly less detailed version is provided as a potential answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate this almost exactly. Running under an IDE debugger, it works perfectly, but if it's not attached to a debugger, or running as a release version, it silently fails to store the token and everything else that comes after the attempted persistence usually fails to run as well.

I managed to resolve this same issue on Android by implementing my own cache derived from `TokenCache` and looking at what it was trying to do.

I located an example for a desktop app, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-native-dotnet

and then had a look at their `FileCache` as it was defined in their GitHub repo:

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-NativeClient-DotNet/blob/complete/TaskClient/FileCache.cs

I copied their `FileCache`, and added it to the `PublicClientApplication` initialisation :

```
ClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(SharedConstants.AuthContext, SharedConstants.ClientId)
{
  RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
  UserTokenCache = new FileCache(),
};
```

(by default most examples leave the `UserTokenCache` property empty, to presumably use the platform default shared prefs).

Then tweaked it to do some verbose logging during the reads/writes/accesses just to see what it was up to:

```
private void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
{
  // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
  try
  {
    this.Log().Debug("About to update token cache (if it's changed)...");
    if (this.HasStateChanged)
    {
      this.Log().Debug("State has changed, updating cache file...");
      lock (FileLock)
      {
        // reflect changes in the persistent store
        _file.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath, this.Serialize());
        // once the write operation took place, restore the HasStateChanged bit to false
        this.HasStateChanged = false;
      }
      this.Log().Debug("Token cache file updated");
    }
    this.Log().Debug("Finished updating token cache file");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    this.Log().ErrorException($"Something went wrong during token AfterAccessNotification: {ex.Message}", ex);
  }
}
```

The logging showed that on Android, it was throwing an exception related to there not being a serialisation handler for a `DateTimeOffset`-type property somewhere deep in the bowels of the MSAL library.

Once I wrapped the `AfterAccessNotification` in a try-catch with a handler to log that the exception had occurred, it all started working perfectly.

I've stuck with using this version of `FileCache` for now, because it mostly solves my problem for the moment, but it does mean that the auth tokens etc. aren't stored securely now.

*I suspect the same problem occurs on iOS 10.x on the simulator as well, but I've not been able to verify this yet.*

I hope this helps someone.

Edit: as @Henrik has mentioned in his comment: editing the project properties and telling it **not** to link the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` on Android then fixes the problem permanently. Based on my (admittedly) limited testing, it's then safe to switch away from using the `FileCache` to the default behaviour again.

Comment: Thank you for this! The Serialize method in TokenCache indeed throws an exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: No set method for property 'OffsetMinutes' in type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeOffsetAdapter'. Some had advised to skip linking the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly in the Android project, and this solved the issue immediately.

Comment: fantastic! would you be willing/able to perhaps mark this as the answer? obviously I can't do this myself ;)

Comment: Skipping linking of "System.Runtime.Serializaton" will it give any other issue some where else in project? Like any non-workable scenarios because of this skip. Thanks

Comment: @Suchith I have no idea, I guess it'll depend on what you are building that requires S.R.S to be physically linked into your app. I suspect not tho, it just means that S.R.S gets distributed as the full dll in your app.